# How to consume SOAP web service in Firefox OS?

Tags: javascript, web-services, soap, firefox-os

What is best-practice way of consuming a SOAP web service in Firefox OS?

Are there any Firefox OS specific issues I should pay attention to or it comes down to a problem of consuming a web service from JavaScript (where I can use JQuery AJAX or similar)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There shouldn't be any Firefox OS-specific issues - if/when you could make it work in a browser (preferably a Firefox browser, that is) then it should work just fine in Firefox OS, too.

Although one issue might arise, if the SOAP service doesn't serve [CORS allow-origin headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), in which case your XMLHttpRequest would fail as the OS won't allow cross-origin XHR-s. You could overcome this by creating a [Privileged](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Apps/Packaged_apps) application, that requests in the [webapp manifest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Apps/Manifest) the [SystemXHR permission](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Apps/App_permissions), in which case you are [allowed to make cross-origin requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#Non-standard_properties) to remote services, regardless of CORS headers.